# mandi clash with xcolor?

Tags: beamer

I am getting an error when trying to use mandi in a beamer file.
The error it produces is as follows

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mandi/mandi.sty:39:
>   LaTeX Error: Option
>    clash for package xcolor.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.39 \RequirePackage
>                       {enumitem}

My MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color,tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mandi}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> Eggs
  \item<2-> Plants
\note[item]<2>{Tell joke about plants.}
\note[item]<2>{Make it short.}
  \item<3-> Animals
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there some clash between Mandi and xcolor. I am using overleaf.The error persists even after removal of physics package. I also tried removing one package at a time. Only when I remove mandi the errors go away.

Comment: If you use `\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,hyperref={hypertexnames=false}]{beamer}` this and the next clash will disappear, but then many more problems will arise. I'm thinking that this `mandi` package is incompatible with the `physics` package. I'm not sure though...

Comment: yes true. l tried  it out just now

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `mandi` is incompatible with `beamer`: the latter defines `\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{\translate{Problem}}` in `beamerbasetheorems.sty` and `mandi` wants to define a `problem` environment. At least that's the first issue showing up after fixing the options, did not examine others.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: You don't need to load `graphics`, `color`, and `hyperref` with beamer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mandi` <strike>package</strike> template is based on the the textbook "Matter & Interactions 1" by Ruth Chabay and Bruce Sherwood. It makes a lot of settings which probably all make good sense when typing a book or a similar document, but I think it is not a good idea to use this in combination with beamer.

- it loads several packages which are either incompatible with beamer (for example `enumitem`), don't make any sense (e.g. `float`) and even for compatible packages it does not check if the package is already loaded and if the options are compatible.
- it brutally overwrites many of beamer carefully chosen settings. For example by setting `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue}` the complete colour scheme beamer uses for its navigation and table of contents will be lost.
- its incompatibility with beamer is not the only problem, it also conflicts with both the `physics` and the `braket` package. Because both of these packages are more careful with their definitions, so you can solve this by loading them after `mandi`. However this might mean that not all their commands will work as expected.

If you still want to use it after this rant, you can load it like this (no guarantee that it won't break further things)

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},noamsthm,hyperref={hypertexnames=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mandi}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{physics}


\begin{document}

\section{title} 

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am the author/maintainer of `mandi` and it was designed with very specific needs in mind. I am in the process of revising it, and I am considering splitting it into two packages. I will try to make it more compatible with `Beamer` if you can specify what that might entail. I can’t guarantee full compatibility though because the needs of my target audience must come first.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Would you mind to meet in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41 ?